# Number of elements is not changed in EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

The component `Grid` is like below:

```
export class GridComponent {
    @Output('modelChanged') modelChangedEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    private valueChanged(newValue: any, item: Object, prop: string) {
        item[prop] = newValue;
        this.emitChangedData();
    }

    private deleteItem() {
        this.data = this.data.filter(function (e) {
            return e !== this.toBeDeletedItem;
        });
        this.emitChangedData();
    }

     private emitChangedData() {
        this.modelChangedEmitter.emit({
            data: this.data
        });
     }

}
```

So, when a value is changed or deleted, the `EventEmitter` emits the current state of data to the container component. When a value is changed, it is correctly sent to the container component, so it works. However, if an element is filtered (and which is effectively filtered in Grid Component), the emitted data has still the same number of items.

This is the container components initialization:

```
<grid [title]="'This is the grid title'" (modelChanged)="dataChanged(data)"></grid>
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `() =>` instead of `function ()`

```
private deleteItem() {
    this.data = this.data.filter((e) => {
        return e !== this.toBeDeletedItem;
    });
    this.emitChangedData();
}
```

to ensure `this.` keeps pointing to the current class.

**update according to comments**

```
<grid (modelChanged)="dataChanged($event)"></grid>
```

instead of

```
<grid (modelChanged)="dataChanged(data)"></grid>
```

Comment: its the same result. changed in grid component but not in parent component. What was the point to use `=>` instead of `function`?

Comment: To ensure `this.toBeDeletedItem` points to the `toBeDeletedItem` you expect not some `data` in limbo

Comment: This is true! Changing function solved the problem. It didn't work for me for the first time because (to try out) i had changed the parameter `$event` to `data` in my parent initialization (see question updated). Thus, It would be better if you add to your answer that it should also be  `<grid (modelChanged)="dataChanged($event)"></grid>` instead of `<grid (modelChanged)="dataChanged(data)"></grid>`